# Take the last part of the folder path in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

If you type pwd you get something like:

`/home/username/Desctop/myfolder/`

How to take the last part? The `myfolder` path.

This must be simple but I couldn't find easy solution in shell. I know how to take care of this in java but not in shell.

thanks

Comment: I don't think that's correct: the output of `pwd` does **not** contain a trailing `/`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You're right--it's a quick command:

```
basename "$PWD"
```

Comment: That's at least one useless expensive fork. What about using `$PWD`?

Answer (score 15):

Using `basename $(pwd)` are **two useless and expensive forks**.

```
echo "${PWD##*/}"
```

should do the trick completely in the shell without expensive forks (snag: for the root directory this is the empty string).

Comment: Only thing is that the last `/` gets removed in `basename` (may not a pply with $PWD but in other custom paths it may. Still I'd choose this method over it. Another `${VAR%/}` (before) is not difficult. +1 for the answer, and also mentioning the word **expensive**.

Answer (score 2):

In Linux, there are a pair of commands, `dirname` and `basename`. `dirname` extracts all but the last part of a path, and `basename` extracts just the last part of a path.

In this case, using `basename` will do what you want:

`basename $(pwd)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `basename` for that, provided the last part is indeed a directory component (not a file):

```
$ basename /home/username/Desctop/myfolder/
myfolder
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract the last part of a path, try using `basename`...

```
basename $(pwd);
```

Comment: The best answer so far, It works in my mac but Im unsure about what linux distros this cmd is available.

Answer (score 0):

```
function basename {
    shopt -s extglob
    __=${1%%+(/)}
    [[ -z $__ ]] && __=/ || __=${__##*/}
}

basename "$PWD"
echo "$__"
```