# Script for removing the words in the line

Tags: shell

Is there any script for removing the words in the line for example these:

> "my_name/your_name/ours_name/name"
>   "my_name/name"

I want to remove the words within the double quotes and before the last slash. Whatever the word appear, I need to remove it. After removing, both of them should be:

> "name"

To be more specific: I have one folder, in that folder there are multiple files. Each file consists of a header file like `#include "my_name/ur_name/name"`. I want it to be `#include "name"`, because I want to make that header in the current directory.

Comment: What language do you want? Actually what have you tried or searched for?

Comment: Is there something you tried ? What is the language we're talking about ? Platform ? Honestly, dude

Comment: @totymedli shell script

Comment: Your example is confusing IMO.  Show us what you have before, and what you want after the change. Is it shell script in Linux, or batch file in Windows?

Comment: @foxidrive shell script in linux.

Answer (score 1):

you can try the below command,

**Commmand:**

```
sed -i 's|#include "my_name/ur_name/name"|#include "name"|g' *
```

**Description:**

command will replace (`#include "my_name/ur_name/name"`)  with (`#include "name"`) into all the files of directory

**NOTE:**
   Command immediately returns "OK" message,But it will take time to perform the internal file operations.

Answer (score 0):

### Shell file

Create a file called `main.sh` and copy this:

```
#Get parameter.
string=$1
#Explode string to array.
IFS='/' read -a array <<< "$string"
#Get array size.
size=${#array[@]}
#Get last array element.
echo ${array[$size-1]}
```

### BASH usage

Now you can call `main.sh` with the path between double quotes as a parameter and it will return the last segment.

> $bash -f main.sh "my_name/your_name/ours_name/name"
>   name
>   $bash -f main.sh "my_name/name"
>   name

Maybe you should also look at this question: [Take the last part of the folder path in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10654135)

Comment: The string is not matter..the string could be any thing..that is one of the string. There are several strings. i cant change it all right??? that's why i indicate with in the quotes.

Comment: You can give anything as the parameter. If it contains at least one `/` character it will give you back everything that comes after the last `/`. That's what you asked for...

Comment: It is not working for me. I have created main.sh in the folder where all my files contain. I did the same as u mentioned. After $bash -f main.sh "my_name/your_name/ours_name/name", i checked in the files, same my_name/your_name/ours_name/name is exists.

Comment: You asked two different things in one question. First you wanted a script that manipulates a string, for this you can see my answer above. Your second request was a much bigger task, where you need to get into all of the files, read them, get the double quote strings, manipulate them then save the file. You can't except from us to do your whole job. Do some reserch, try something then ask again. If you are under 100 lines to modify, it would be easier to replace the texts by hand than write this script. Please delete your second question and ask it in a different post.

Answer (score 0):

A Simple one line will do this

## file.txt

```
"my_name/your_name/ours_name/name"
"my_name/x_name"
```

## Command

```
sed 's/^"//g' file.txt | awk 'BEGIN {FS="/"} {print $NF}' | sed 's/^/"/g'
```

## Output

```
"name"
"x_name"
```